# Storing the current Year from one table to another on year change using trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update, sql-date-functions

I have a table named 'Table1' which has a Primary key column named *ID* and a column named *CreatedAt* of type date.

I have another table named 'MaxLastId' in which I want to store the max *ID* value of 'Table1' when year changes using an AFTER INSERT trigger.

For example, if **Table1**'s data is:

```
ID    | CreatedAt
16    | 31-Dec-2019
17    | 01-Jan-2020
```

...  **MaxLastId** table data should become:

**maxId**

16

As 16 was the value of *ID* of the last row inserted in the Year 2019. The same should happen for the year 2020 and 2021 and so on.

'MaxLastId' table must contain only one row. After every year the only row in MaxLastId will be updated.

What I have tried so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SaveLastYearMaxId]
ON Table1
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM MaxLastId)
    BEGIN
         IF (SELECT DATEDIFF(yy,(SELECT CreatedOn from inserted), (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table1 WHERE id <(SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table1)))) = 1
         -- ( max - second max as first max is 'inserted' already)
         BEGIN
            INSERT INTO MaxLastId SELECT id from inserted
         END    
    END     
ELSE
    BEGIN       
        IF (SELECT DATEDIFF(yy,(SELECT CreatedOn from inserted), (SELECT CreatedOn from Table1 where id = (Select [maxId] from MaxLastId)))) = 1
            BEGIN
                UPDATE MaxLastId SET [maxId] = (SELECT id from inserted)
            END 
    END 
END
```

I have questions:

- Will this trigger do the job? If yes, can this trigger be written any better?
- Is there a better approach to solve this problem?

I am not very good at SQL triggers.

Comment: This is not going to work from one year to the next, unless you are truncating the table somehow.  I would suggest storing the maximum id per year.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and answer. Can you please guide me, what if I truncate and then add the new row instead of UPDATE? I only want one record in this table. What do you suggest?

Comment: Wouldn't it be significantly simpler to schedule some sort of job to run at Jan 1st at 12 AM to write that record?

Comment: I have not written a scheduled job before. Can you please elaborate it a little bit more?

Answer (score 1):

The most important thing is that `inserted` could have multiple rows, so your trigger is not correct.

I would put the year into the lookup table:

```
create table maxlastid (
    year int unique,
    lastid int
);
```

I am trying to think of a way of doing this without locking the entire table and serializing inserts.  This is challenging in a multi-threaded environment.  The idea is:

1. Attempt to insert the *maximum id* into the table.
2. If no rows are updated, then insert a row.
3. If that fails, insert a new row.

This code looks like:

```
begin
    declare @maxid int;

    select @maxid = max(id)
    from inserted;


    update maxlastid
        set maxid = (case when lastid > @maxid then lastid else @maxid end)
        where year = year(getdate());

    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin try
        insert into maxlastid (year, lastid)
            values (year(getdate()), @maxid);
    end try;
    begin catch
        -- if the year already exists, try inserting again
        update maxlastid
            set maxid = (case when lastid > @maxid then lastid else @maxid end)
            where year = year(getdate());

        -- otherwise ignore
    end catch;
end;
```

This may still have some subtle race condition.  So actually using transactions and locking is recommended.

Comment: Can you please check this line   'set maxid = (case when maxlastid > maxid then maxlastid else maxid end)'? Shouldn't maxlastid be lastid?

Comment: Sir can you please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193382/auto-generating-value-for-a-field-based-on-the-value-of-primary-key-current-yea

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend to simply use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.vMaxLastId AS
  SELECT YEAR(CreatedAt) AS [Year], MAX(Id) AS [MaxId] 
    FROM Table1 
    GROUP BY YEAR(CreatedAt)
```

If you have a lot of data (millions of records) and it becomes slow to use you'll need to add index or make it a clustered view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Don't you think ORDER BY should be GROUP BY?

Comment: Yes, I meant GROUP BY,  order by is not even allowed in views...

Comment: Sir can you please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193382/auto-generating-value-for-a-field-based-on-the-value-of-primary-key-current-yea

Comment: The problem is that if a record is deleted then the view is also updated. For example, If the max record for a year is in the view and the year changes and then the max record for the previous year is deleted from the parent table then the view will be updated. But the max record for the previous year should be stored somewhere as per my requirement.

Comment: It is certainly going to reflect only the existing data and not deleted.

Comment: THATS THE ISSUE!!